# Two websockets with BinanceSocketManager

Tags: python, websocket, binance

I'm trying to open two web sockets - depth book and user socket.

Here's my code:

```
async def sockets(client):
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    ds = bm.depth_socket("BTCUSDT", depth=BinanceSocketManager.WEBSOCKET_DEPTH_5)
    
    print("Started...")

    async with ds as depth_socket:
        while True:
            res = await depth_socket.recv()
            print(res)

    await client.close_connection()
```

I need `bm.user_socket()` socket to be opened as well at the same time.

How can I have two of them opened at the same time with BinanceSocketManager?

Comment: Why not? The implementation depends on the desired behavior. And you need to show what you want to do with the `recv()` returns from those sockets.

Comment: For now just a response is enough just like I did with depth socket.

Comment: In that case, two coroutines yield from two `depth_socket()`?

Comment: No? I need to open two sockets - user socket and depth socket...

Comment: do you still need this?

Comment: Yes, @AlexB. I've been looking for the answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do with bm.user_socket() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've amended your code because it wasn't working. My feeling is that you don't have a good understanding of how `asyncio` works. I would recommend you read this [tutorial](https://tutorialedge.net/python/concurrency/asyncio-event-loops-tutorial/) on `asyncio` event loops.

What you need is to run *multiple coroutines* using `asyncio`'s `ensure_future` module which will enable you to *schedule tasks* and run them *asynchronously*.

What we are doing in the code below is we are creating separate tasks for `depth_socket` and `user_socket` which loop indefinately but also run asynchronously so they can return data whenever it is sent by the server without waiting for the other task to finish.

I think the problem you were having is that you were trying to put both `depth_socket` and `user_socket` in the same `async` coroutine so looping indefinately with `depth_socket` meant that you could never loop through the `user_socket` concurrently.

There's a section on running multiple coroutines in the tutorial link I have given you above which helped me a lot understand how this works.

Unfortunately I can't seem to connect to the binance testnet so I haven't been able to test if the `user_socket` task actually works when a user event occurs but it should as it's not throwing an error when connected to livenet. Let me know if you are getting trade events.

You will need to input your api key and secret of course.

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager

api_key = '...'
api_secret = '...'

async def task_depth_socket():
    client = await AsyncClient.create(api_key, api_secret)
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    ds = bm.depth_socket("BTCUSDT", depth=BinanceSocketManager.WEBSOCKET_DEPTH_5)

    async with ds as depth_socket:
        while True:
            res = await depth_socket.recv()
            print(res)
    
async def task_user_socket():
    client = await AsyncClient.create(api_key, api_secret)
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    us = bm.user_socket()
    
    async with us as user_socket:
        while True:
            res = await user_socket.recv()
            print(res)    
 
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(task_depth_socket())
    asyncio.ensure_future(task_user_socket())
    loop.run_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    print("Closing Loop")
    loop.close()
```

Comment: I need open two sockets at the same time with BinanceSocketManager, namely User Socket and Depth Socket as you shown... Because with one I can get trade updates and the other I can use for strategy purpose. Also, I have a question... do we really "await client.close_connection()? That closes the entire client. How could I just stop the sockets only, if i wanted to?

Comment: I've updated the answer. As for `await client.close_connection()` it is not required here since you are running a `while True` loop which runs forever so you are never going to need to close the connection.

Comment: Thank you! How would I stop the loop, if I wanted to?

Comment: I've added a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception so when you press Ctrl+C it will close the loop.

Comment: I know that, haha. But like... when a program is running.. you have two loops and you want to close one of them? How do we do that? For example, I want to stop only "depth book" loop...

Comment: It depends. What are the conditions to stop the loop? regular time interval? keyboard interupt? Can you give a specific example?

Comment: You know, just like stopping one of the loops without closing the entire program itself (having one loop running).